# Get current state inside the payload

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

In react, if we want to make a calculation which is based on a property set inside the state, we can write the `setState` as follows:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5)
// instead of this: 
// setCounter(counter + 1)
// you can do this:
setCounter((previousState)=> previousState + 1)
```

This is one of the fundamentals in react.

Is there a similar thing in redux toolkit where I can for instance do something as follows:

```
import { setCounter } from 'features/posSlice'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  dispatch(setCounter((previousState) => previousState + 1))
}
```

Now you might ask, *why you don't implement this inside the reducers?* so by doing something as follows:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const posSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'pos',
  initialState: {
    counter: 5
  },
  reducers: {
    incrementBy = (state, { payload }) => {
       state.counter = state.counter + payload
    }
  }
})
```

Just for now, let's make it simple:

I would like to know if there's a method to get the current state *among all these async calls* TO get the **correct..current..state** in order to build upon it. from inside the controllers, not the models.

So, something like this inside the component, not the slice:

```
import { setCounter } from 'features/posSlice'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  dispatch(setCounter((previousState) => previousState + 1))
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3122#issuecomment-1404879054

> I'm sorry, but the question is really "why you don't implement this
> inside the reducers".
>
> Caclulation of new state should always happen in a reducer - you
> should only pass stuff you need for that calculation into the payload,
> never the new value. Please give the Redux Style Guide a good read.
>
> That said, you can do this in a thunk, although I would really
> recommend against it.
>
> dispatch((dispatch, getState) => {
> dispatch(setCounter(getState().yourCounterValue + 1)) })

So simply do it as

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

// inside a component
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch((dispatch, getState)=>{
 dispatch(getState().pos.counter + 1)
})
```